# Non Wordpress file/ folder in public_html not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have installed WordPress in the root directory. There is a folder "order" and "admin3" in the same directory. I can not open this folder www.mysite.com/order with this URL or any file inside of it www.mysite.com/order/login.php. When I open this file I get " is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500".

I have tried this on the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/order/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Error 500 can be anything. What is error message from error log?

Comment: There is nothing in my error log relating to the error 500 and everything in my WordPress works. i just can't navigate to non WordPress files or folder